# Ajax request executing OPTIONS method instead of GET, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. ASP.NET Core, Nginx

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, nginx, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing Asp.net core application on Windows and Deplaying on Ubuntu, I won't do this anymore. I know that when you break the same origin policy you get the error of the options method being executed but I am not breaking anything.  I am using Nginx as proxy server for kestrel. I set up the environment like this: [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x). I assume that nginx is listening on port 8080 and handling the request to Kestrel on port 5000.  This is my request.

```
           $.ajax({
               method: 'GET',
               url: 'http://localhost/autocompletar-pesquisa',
               data: { palavrasChave: palavrasChave }, 
               dataType: 'JSON',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               success: function (data) {
           ....
```

Here is the error I get on Chrome

[image]

Here is the error I get on Firefox

[image]

I call to  http://my_ip/autocompletar-pesquisa?palavrasChave=eficiente

returns data normally

[image]

Comment: FYI no need for contentType with a GET  request

Comment: I took contentType and no luck. The problem is with ajax request. POSTs are also failing.